# Is there tool or wireshark plugin for filtering JSON pcap?

Tags: json, wireshark

I know JSON messages are just key and value, but is there a wireshark plugin or tool available for filtering JSON messages within a pcap ?

For Eg:- Let say i have below 4 json message(s) within a pcap

```
{"name":"john","salary":50000,"email":"john@stackoverflow.com"}
{"name":"vj","salary":55000,"email":"vj@stackoverflow.com"}
{"name":"rj","salary":65000,"email":"rj@stackoverflow.com"}
{"name":"rambo","salary":66000,"email":"rambo@stackoverflow.com"}
```

I want to filter out all the people whose salary is less than 65000 ?

snippet code

```
func filter_packet_based_on_rule(json_packet)
{
    // In this case if salary is < 65000, but it could be more complex
    if json_packet matches any of the rule
        return true
    else
        return false
}

main()
{
    while true
        json_packet = read_packet_from_pcap()
        if ! json_packet { break; }

        if (filter_packet_based_on_rule(json_packet))
            print json_packet 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What language are you trying to write this in? Can you post code or what you think the algorithm should look like?

Comment: @RossJacobs - Update the algorithm that i m looking for.. Preference would be c/c++/python/go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your are looking for something like this - https://github.com/ranjithum/Json-Analyzer/

All-though there is not code to parse the pcap (which shouldn't be hard using libpcap), u could write your own filtering rules and filter out necessary packets.